# Why Can't I see my android device in DDMS Perspective Mode in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I turned on the usb-debugging mode and installed kies (drivers).
What else should I do?

I use MIUI.US Rom

Edit:

My device is Galaxy S I9000. I try to debug a program that I wrote through the device, but I can't see the device in eclipse. 
I tried:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: I added some info. Do you understand now what is my problem?

Comment: I think he means the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  Developer questions are off-topic here, but hopefully the [SO] people can help you with Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me twice. Two different issues. The first was a bad USB cable. It would mount but not debug. The second was that I had to reinstall the Google USB drivers for the phone debugging. They are in your SDK install location under extras/google/usb_driver. You should see a device with an exclamation mark in device manager. Just update that driver with the one listed above.

Comment: My solution was that second option

Answer (score 2):

I failed to get the Google drivers to work with Samsung devices over ADB.

Install Samsung Kies and it will assist in installing the required OEM drivers for you.

Comment: After installing KIES the Google drivers still won't load; SPH-D700 running CM 10.1 (4.2.2). Dell Inspiron M5030, AMD Athlon II P360.

Comment: Kies installs the Samsung drivers, not the google ones ... not sure if this will work with Cyanogen ... you may want to try the CM forums

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, in your command prompt

```
adb devices
```

see if it shows the list of devices attached

if not , then make sure you have debugging enabled on your test device
To enable debugging go to

```
Phone Settings --> Applications --> Development --> Enable USB Debugging
```

Check mark it , the try `adb devices`

Comment: Didn't help still can't see my device

Comment: can you mount your device in Storage Mode ? do you see the USB debugging connected when connected via USB ?

Comment: Yes, I can mount it in storage mode and I can see the debugging icon when connected.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I just encountered the same thing and solved it by simply REBOOTING the android device. Who would've thought huh?

Anyway, I am using android studio in stead of eclipse and a one-plus one device running Cyanogenmod 12.0, it wouldn't show up in the Android Device Monitor even though the drivers were installed, usb debugging was turned on and after revoking USB debugging authorisations multiple times and plugging it in and out of different USB ports, rebooting finally solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with one plus one this is how I resolved it

**SetUp Android Debugging**

- Go to settings -> About Device and tap on Build number for 7 times it will unlock Developers Option feature in settings.
- In Developers option check Usb debugging

**SetUp Drivers**

- Go to `My Computer` right click properties
- Select `Device Manager` from left menu,
- In Device manager find the Android device, and select Update
  Driver Software.
- Select `Browse my computer` for driver software instead of Online search.
- Next select `let me pick from a list of device drivers` on my computer
- Select `Android driver` from list of drivers If you get a warning, select Yes to continue.